# How do I properly use the Round() function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

So I am trying to use the built-in round function in Python but for some reason, the program runs properly sometimes and other times it doesn't

```
for i in range(0, inp):
    temp = restaurant.getEmployee() * random.randint(1, 5) * hours * average
    print(round(temp, 2))
    weekly += round(temp, 2)
    restaurant.changeMoney(round(temp, 2))

print("\nThe restaurant earned $" + str(weekly))
print("The restaurant has a total of $" + str(restaurant.getMoney()))
```

This is the result that I get:

```
3622.32
1448.93
724.46
1448.93
3622.32

The restaurant earned $10866.960000000001
The restaurant has a total of $11266.960000000001
```

Sometimes the code works properly and I get something along the lines of this:

```
3421.44
684.29
684.29
2737.15
3421.44

The restaurant earned $10948.61
The restaurant has a total of $11248.61
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: If you're working with monetary amounts in dollars, then do all of your work in integer cents and convert only when you print.

Comment: either what Tim says^ or use `Decimal` instead of `float`